# How to pass a strongly typed model and a list of models to a view simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

My end goal is to pass a strongly typed model (to populate a drop-down menu) and a list of models (based on a search query) to a view simultaneously from a controller. The view I am passing it to is the "Clear()" view. Currently in my HomeController.cs I have:

```
public ActionResult Clear()
    {
        var states = GetAllStates();

        var model = new ProjectClearanceApp.Models.Project();

        model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);

        return View(model);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetAllStates()
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
            "AL",
             // ... (you get the point)
            "WY",
        };
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
    {
        var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = element,
                Text = element
            });
        }

        return selectList;
    }
```

I read somewhere that that's the best way to get the list of options for a drop-down menu. Now I'd also like a pass a LIST of models to the same view (Clear.cshtml) based on a search query. I'm reading [from this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search) to search in the controller action for that view by adding

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var movies = from m in db.Movies
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(movies);
}
```

to the controller. How can I pass both the list of drop-down options AND the list of models that fit the search from the controller to the view (or, how can I achieve the same effect without passing both from the controller)?

Comment: via another model that encapsulates them both

Comment: There is never any reason to write `from x in y select x`.

Comment: @SLaks That's a good point. How can I rewrite the `select` statement to do the search while selecting instead of getting the full list of movies from the database and then searching it?

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald `var movies = db.Movies.AsQueriable();`

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald You don't need to do anything.  Accessing `db.Movies` doesn't load anything until you enumerate.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, I'll have to look into .AsQueriable() because I'm not familiar with it. Also, what type does the `select` statement return? In other words what variable type should my list be in my new model? `IEnumerable<Movies>`?

Comment: @SLaks Well if I don't have `from x in y select x`, then the `movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));` will cause an error because `movies` will be null. I'm asking how I can rewrite the code to have the same functionality without using `from x in y select x`.

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald: Just use `db.Movies`, and declare it as `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model` is a term that really describes what data is meant to be bound to the view, and what data the model binder will handle when you make a request to/from the view.  Because I'm not exactly sure how you are using Index and Clear, I'll just stub these out generally. Please let me know if I've missed the point of your question:

If you are having trouble passing, for example, `List<Movies> movieModel` along with your `List<SelectListItem> selectedStates` (or any additional values) to the view, here are 2 common ways to do this.

1. ViewModel approach -- Create a model class that contains your "main" model along with any other properties, lists, etc. that you'll need in the view.
   eg:

   ```
   public Class MyViewModelClass
   {
      List<Movie> MoviesList {get;set;}
      List<SelectListItem> StatesList {get;set;}
      //some other properties/methods can go here as well ...
   }

   //In Controller
   {
       MyViewModelClass model = new MyViewModelClass();
       model.StatesList = <build your select list>;
       model.MovieList = <build your movie list>;

       return View(model);
   }
   ```

In the controller you would then create a new instance of `MyViewModelClass model` (different name obviously), and populate your movie list, state list, and any other properties, assign them to the model properties, and pass the whole thing as your `return View(model);`

This is nice because all of the data getting passed to the view can be in one place.

2. ViewBag approach -- Stick with a single model or List, and pass view-related data (such as dropdown lists, or state bools) in the ViewData or ViewBag.
   ex.

   ```
   //From Controller
   public ActionResult SomeMethod()
   {
      var states = GetAllStates();
      var model = <enter movies query here>;
      ViewBag.StatesList = GetSelectListItems(states);
      //This will be accessible in the view now

      return View(model);
   }

   //In View:
   @{
       List<SelectListItem> StatesList =  (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatesList; // Can now use this variable to bind to DropDownList, etc.
    }
   ```

I prefer, for the most part, using a ViewModel to add everything I need. For one, the ViewBag/ViewData requires some casting, and it relies on "magic strings", so you don't have Visual Studio letting you know if you'd typed something wrong with intellisense. That said, either is viable.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your end goal ,that is passing the list of model, viewmodel will be the best solution as per my knowledge.

**Some key note above view model:**

The ViewModel class, which is the bridge between the view and the model. Each View class has a corresponding ViewModel class. The ViewModel retrieves data from the Model and manipulates it into the format required by the View. It notifies the View if the underlying data in the model is changed, and it updates the data in the Model in response to UI events from the View

The ViewModel class determines whether a user action requires modification of the data in the Model, and acts on the Model if required. For example, if a user presses a button to update the inventory quantity for a part, the View simply notifies the ViewModel that this event occurred. The ViewModel retrieves the new inventory amount from the View and updates the Model. This decouples the View from the Model, and consolidates the business logic into the ViewModel and the Model where it can be tested.

**Official definition/ Source:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx

**Additional information with Ex:**

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-viewmodel-in-aspnet-mvc

Kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik